# cannot push element to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic2

I'm trying to push elements to the end of the array called "toServiceSubCatNamesList"

```
this.toServiceSubCatNamesList.push(this.loadServiceTypes.serviceTypes[j]);
```

The structure of "loadServiceTypes" array is:

```
{
"serviceTypes": [
    {
        "service_type_id": 1,
        "service_type_name": "Cutting",
        "service_type_price": "3000.00",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
            "service_service_type_service_id": 1,
            "service_service_type_service_type_id": 1
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

The structure of "toServiceSubCatNamesList" array is:

```
toServiceSubCatNamesList > 0:Object
                                 created_at:null
                                 pivot:Object
                                 service_type_id:1
                                 service_type_name:"Washing"
                                 service_type_price:"3000.00"
                                 updated_at:null
                                 __proto__:Object
                                 length:1
                                 __proto__:Array(0)
```

When I'm doing this It will gives the error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'service_type_name' of undefined".Any suggetions to overcome this!

Comment: How and where are you accessing the array `toServiceSubCatNamesList`?

Comment: this.toServiceSubCatNamesList.push(this.loadServiceTypes.serviceTypes[j]);

Comment: It's an object, not an array. You'll need something like `this.toServiceSubCatNamesList[j]=this.loadServiceTypes.ser‌​viceTypes[j];`

Comment: I think this error does not from your push function. Search for where do you use `service_type_name` in your file and check it

Comment: I agree with @Duannx. Somewhere in your code you try to access the property `service_type_name` on an object that is not defined.

Comment: Please provide the entire code of your component and template.